# TimeoutError related to Anaconda

Tags: python, image, anaconda, timeout, jupyter

I'm trying to run a python code in Jupyter Notebook. I think I've installed all the modules I need to run the code, but I'm getting these errors and I'm trying to understand what they are:

[image: TimeoutError. It looks like it's related to Anaconda.]

I tried uninstalling Anaconda and reinstalling the latest version, but I still get this error shown here:

Comment: It can be difficult to suggest an answer seeing only the error. Consider adding some code that triggers the error (see [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: I'm hesitant to modify the code, because it was sent to me and it works on others' computers. So I'm inclined to think there is an issue with my installation of anaconda or jupyter or something with my computer?

Comment: Did they provide you with a YAML file to define the environment they normally run the code in?

Comment: No, it doesn't look like it. I've never used gitlab before, but from what I can tell, the gitlab directory has the code itself and some custom modules needed to run the code. 

But when I try to run it, I get the "TimeoutError" and it lists directories in my anaconda3 folder, which is why I keep thinking the problem is there. But I already uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda with no change.